# How to get spring boot controller endpoint full url?

Tags: spring, url, spring-boot, controller, endpoint

How to get a specific spring boot controller endpoint full url without concat/hardcode strings? My case is need send a request to external url and get async notification back from it, so I need pass my notification endpoint full url to it. Here is sample code:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
    public class MyController {

       @PostMapping("/sendRequest")
       public void sendRequest() {
          ...
          // 1. get /notifyStatus endpoint full url to be send to external service
          String myNotificationFullUrl = xxx ?
          // 2. call external service
       }

       @GetMapping("/notifyStatus")
       public void notifyStatus() {
          ...
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allows getting any URL on your system, not just a current one.

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder
...
ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(YourController.class).getSomeEntityMethod(parameterId, parameterTwoId))

URI methodUri = linkBuilder.Uri()
String methodUrl = methodUri.getPath()
```

There are more methods also to change a host name, etc.

Comment: @Cyva It gives the LAN ip. are there any way to get the public URL using hateoas

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want hardcode, maybe a possible solution is add a messages.properties with all your messages and urls. Then you can configure Spring MessageSource and get your url from that file.

Supose that you have a message.properties file with the following property:

```
url=full_url_to_your_service
```

In your `@Controller`, inject your configured MessageSource to allow Spring resolve the messages:

```
 @Autowired
 private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Then you can get your url as follow:

```
String url= messageSource.getMessage("url", put_here_your_locale);
```

If you need more information, check [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) for MessageSource.